# Probability that player wins the game (Markov chains)

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expected-value, gambling

Players A and B take turns in answering trivia questions, starting with player A answering the first question. Each time A answers, she has a probability p1 of getting it right. Each time B plays, he has probability p2 of getting it right. Suppose that first player to answer correctly wins the game. What is the probability that A wins?

Attempt 1: I approached it with Markov chains with states $(A, B, win)$ representing A playing, B playing, and A winning the game respectively. If (pA, pB) denote the probability that A and B wins the game respectively, then I have the set of equations
$$pA = p1 + (1-p1)pB$$ $$pB = (1-p2)pA + p2  $$
The first equation says that if player A plays, she has a probability $p1$ of winning the game and $(1-p1)$ of getting the answer wrong, in which case it is player B's turn. The second equation says that player B has $p2$ chance of winning the game and with probability $(1-p2)$ it is player A's turn. However, the set of equations give the answer $pA=1$ which doesn't make sense.

Attempt 2: I augmented the states with $(A,B, Awins, Bwins)$, giving me the set of equations
$$pA = p1 + (1-p1)pB $$
$$pB = (1-p2)pA + p2*0  $$
The solution to this system is $pA = \frac{p1}{1-(1-p1)(1-p2)}$, which makes sense.

My questions are as follows:

1. Where is the flaw in attempt1?
2. How do we set up the states in such Markov chain type problems?
3. How do we solve this problem in recursive fashion without the knowledge of Markov chains?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't understand your first equation.  I think it's better to write $p_A=p_1+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_A$  Since $A$ must either win on the first turn, or survive the first round, at which point the game resets.

Comment: Note:  your notation is not properly defined.  It makes a big difference who starts the game, so I expect you really want $4$ variables..$P_{X,Y}$ denoting the probability that $X$ will win given that it's $Y's$ turn.  In my simpler equation, $p_A$ means the answer to the problem, namely the probability that $A$ will win given that $A$ is starting.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your comments. I have mentioned that A starts the game. Your equation makes sense- I was just wondering if we can approach it with Markov chains.

Comment: You don't understand...of course $A$ starts the game at first, but after $A$ has missed on the first turn, $B$ is now starting the game.  Thus, using the notation I proposed, $P_{A,A}=p_1\times 1+(1-p_1)P{A,B}$ and $P_{A,B}=p_2\times 0+(1-p_2)p_{A,A}$.   which is already enough to solve the problem.

Comment: Typo:  in my last comment I meant to have written $P_{A,B}$ instead of $PA,B$.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two reasons why Attempt $1$ fails. 1) By setting up this mutually recursive relationship you're making the assumption that $pA$ and $pB$ aren't influenced by the choice of starting player. 2) We must have $pB=1-pA$ since the probability this game continues indefinitely is $0$. Therefore $pB$ can only depend on $p_1$ since $pA$ does not depend on $p_2$. But clearly we know from the problem statement that $pB$ should depend on $p_2$.

Here is how to solve this problem without Markov chains. Assuming player $A$ goes first, the probability $A$ wins within the first $n$ guess is given by $P(A_n)$. Then,
$$P(A_n)=p_1+(1-p_1)(1-p_2)p_1+\cdots+(1-p_1)^{n-1}(1-p_2)^{n-1}p_1$$
E.g. to win on the second guess $A$ must mess up the first guess, have $B$ mess up their guess, and then guess it correctly.
$$P(A)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}P(A_n)=\dfrac{p_1}{1-(1-p_1)(1-p_2)}$$ by convergence of the geometric series since $(1-p_1)(1-p_2)<1$.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I ended up implicitly assuming that $=1−$ in my first attempt. I think by adding a new state, I am resolving this- do you agree? Also, my interpretation of state $Bwins$ is that it is an absorbing state with probability =0. Would that interpretation be correct?

Comment: I wouldn't say your interpretation accurately describes the situation since there is a nonzero chance for the system to rest on $Bwins$. In fact, if you tried solving for $pB$ in that system you would get the wrong answer. However, you did get the right answer for $pA$ so I reckon there's something worthwhile about your method. My interpretation of your method would be $pA$ and $pB$ are the probabilities of ending on $Awins$ when starting on $A$ and $B$ respectively. And then you manually set the probabilities of all absorbing states to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(A) = p_1$ denote the probability that the player A wins a round and $P(F)$ denote the probability that this round is the final one. By applying Bayes' rule we get:

$$ P(A|F) = \frac{P(F|A)P(A)}{P(F)} = \frac{1 \cdot p_1}{1 - (1-p_1)(1-p_2)} $$

Note that the event $A|F$ reads "A wins this round given that it is the last one" means that A actually wins the game.

Comment: It sucks that I can't accept both answers. Thanks for the nice solution.

Comment: No problem. The technique presented in the accepted answer is more general anyways as it can be applied to any game that must eventually end.